# Virtual Directory Not working in local IIS

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I have a virtual directory set up in local IIS to serve up images but when the web page runs it gives a 404 for the images and shows that it is looking at the physical path for the website not the path specified for the virtual directory

I have things set like this:
**IIS7.5**
Site is MyWebSite
physical path is c:\mywebsite
virtual directory for MyWebSite\images has physical path c:\myimages
I can see everything including files in the virtual directory

**Binding**
http 127.0.0.1 port 80 (also tried port 59925)
host header is MyWebSite

**Visual Studio**
Properties>Web set to run in local IIS
project url is set to:  http://localhost/mywebsite

**Windows host file** the last line is
127.0.0.1   localhost
I also tried
127.0.0.1    localhost/mywebsite
127.0.0.1    mywebsite

I run the site from visual studio and it runs fine except for the images.    Clicking on the link in page source opens an error page with a 404 error.  The physical path shown is c:mywebsite instead of c:\myimages.

I am assuming something is wrong with something in the setup above but not sure what it is.

**Edit**
the url in the page source is a relative one

```
img src=../../myimages/myimage.jpg 

Requested URL      http://localhost:80/mywebsite/mymages/image.jpg
Physical Path      C:\MyWebSite\myimages\image.jpg
```

**Edit 2 ** here are the site bindings

```
<sites>
    <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
        <application path="/">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
            </application>
            <application path="/WebSiteManager2019" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\MyWebSite" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="MyWebSite" id="3" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="MyWebSite">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\MyWebSite" />
                <virtualDirectory path="/images" physicalPath="C:\MyImages" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="127.0.0.1:80:MyWebSite" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="DefaultAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
```

Comment: *Clicking on the link in page source* Please post the URL that you see in the source. Is it relative or absolute?

Comment: Run a report and learn your mistakes https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @JohnWu the url in the source is a relative one   <img src=../../myimages/myimage.jpg />

Comment: @JohnWu the url in the source is a relative one      <img src=../../myimages/myimage.jpg />


Requested URL    http://localhost:80/mywebsite/mymages/image.jpg
Physical Path    C:\MyWebSite\myimages\image.jpg